# Form key validate method throws null check operator error

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and am learning about validations in textFormFields and forms. In my app I have a form with a textFormField and a submit button which should stay disabled if form is not valid. I checked flutter docs examples and they have checked for validation the same way. I don't know where I'm going wrong? Here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Program9 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Program9({super.key});

  @override
  State<Program9> createState() => _Program9State();
}

class _Program9State extends State<Program9> {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  bool isEmailValid = true;

  bool getValidEmailCondition(String value) {
    // Check and return valid email conditions
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Program 9'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        child: Form(
          key: formKey,
          autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                controller: emailController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  label: Text(
                    'Email ID',
                    style: kDefaultTextStyle,
                  ),
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                maxLines: 1,
                onTapOutside: (_) =>
                    FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
                validator: (value) {
                  return (getValidEmailCondition(value!))
                      ? null
                      : 'Enter a valid email';
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 50),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: (formKey.currentState!.validate()) ? null : () { //Line causing the error
                  print('Email: ${emailController.text}');
                },
                child: const Text('Submit'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Are you looking for behaviour like this - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vRB0YRNLWVNnZF57R6Gr0rxpe__MFL1X/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't think so. The login button stays active even if the validators are showing. I want that button to be disabled when the validators are showing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the syntax within:

```dart
 onPressed: (formKey.currentState!.validate())
                    ? null
                    : () {
                        print('Email: ${emailController.text}');
                      },
```

Here, you are checking whether the form is valid within the *parameter* of the function!

Also note, as soon as the program *runs* it will throw this error since you are calling the statement using the parenthesis `()`.

Instead, you should do:

```dart
 ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                    // valid
                  } else {
                    // invalid
                  }
                },
                child: const Text('Submit'),
              ),
```

Comment: Actually I wanted to keep the button disabled based on (formKey.currentState!.validate()). I don't think I will be able to keep the button disabled this way. Is there any other way to check if the validator is showing or not?